# Would Suggestion trigger beguiling defenses, and if so what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, conditions

Considering Suggestion isn't technically a charm, but that those who are immune to charms are immune to its effects, does it logically follow that a Warlock could turn suggestion back on the caster? Would the Warlock get to instead tell the caster what they want them to do, would they do what the enemy initially tried to suggest to the caster, or would they just have the charmed condition?

[This question/answer pair](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55452/23847) talks about Fey Ancestry and what happens if you are charmed, but not of suggestion, nor how a Warlock could retaliate to this spell being cast on them.

> **BEGUILING DEFENSES**
>
> Beginning at 10th level, your patron teaches you how to
> turn the mind-affecting magic of your enemies against
> them. You are immune to being charmed, and when
> another creature attempts to charm you, you can use
> your reaction to attempt to turn the charm back on
> that creature. The creature must succeed on a Wisdom
> saving throw against your warlock spell save DC or
> be charmed by you for 1 minute or until the creature takes any damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the rules are concerned, no. You've already made the distinction - Beguiling Defenses only works against being Charmed, and *Suggestion* doesn't Charm. You **are** immune to *Suggestion*, since it specifies that

> Creatures that can't be charmed are immune to this effect.

You can, of course, talk to your DM and ask them to rule that Beguiling Defenses works fully against *Suggestion*. There's definitely a case for it, considering the flavour:

> your patron teaches you how to turn the mind-affecting magic of your enemies against them.

And the fact that Beguiling Defenses makes you immune to *Suggestion*, which suggests (pun intended) that it **should** work, even though it technically doesn't.